# OpenCV - How to loop through pixels in Java?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, camera

I'm trying to use the camera in more complicated ways on our frc team and have just started using OpenCV with Java. I have been trying to loop through all the pixels because I want to get the color values to detect the colors shown through the camera.

I've been able to get pixels using the `.put(col, row, valueToPut)` and `.get(col, row)` methods. But I can't loop through all the pixels (there are 640x480 of them), because our roborio is too slow. I also know that the `.put` and `.get` methods are quite slow.

Does anyone know what I'm supposed to do to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

you can use .get(col, row) to get a row or entire matrix from opencv Mat into a java primitive array and do whatever operations you do on that array and then use put method to put back  the java array to opencv matrix. This way it is much faster than individual pixel accessing. i.e Reducing no of calls to opencv get and put methods will results in better performance.

```
Mat A ;
A.convertTo(A,cvType.CV_16SC3);
int size = (int) (A.total() * A.channels());
short[] temp = new short[size];
A.get(0, 0, temp);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   temp[i] = (short) (temp[i] / 2);
C.put(0, 0, temp);
```

Comment: When i try running this, I get Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 16

Comment: Edited the answer.You must convert your image type to short data type before doing pixel accessing for this particular example.Learning more about opencv datatypes will help you.

Comment: oh ok, Thanks! I actually got it working by using a byte array instead